# Django flush command doesn't clear all tables

Tags: python, sql, django, database, flush

I have a django app that contains 4 modules. Each of is modules store data into a table in the database. Which leaves us with 4 tables.

When I run a flush command in order to delete existing data in these tables :

```
python manage.py flush --noinput
```

It clears data from 2 tables, but leaves data in the 2 other tables.

I find it weird as a behavior. Do you have an idea on how is this possible to solve ?

Comment: Can you share your models and your INSTALLED_APPS setting? The tables that are not flushed, are the models in an installed app and are they managed?

Comment: The tables that are not flushed belong to an installed app. What do you mean by managed ?

Comment: Please add your models.py code to the question and your INSTALLED_APPS setting if possible

Comment: For this app I have 2 tables and their models are included in a folder called models

Comment: Does the models folder have an `__init__.py` file that imports the models? Can you just show your code?

Comment: yes it does include an __init__.py. When I run operations to fill the tables it works well. But the issue happens when I want to flush

Comment: If you remove `--noinput` from the command do you get some prompt/error regarding those tables?

Comment: No errors returned.

Comment: @IainShelvington when I run a migrate it reveals this warning : ` Your models in app(s): 'unifier' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.`

Comment: Run `makemigrations` and then `migrate` so that your migrations are up to date?

Comment: I don't know how, but makemigrations deletes my models.

Comment: That must mean you are not importing your models in `__init__.py` correctly, did you recently refactor your models into separate files in a models folder? Make sure you have `from .<model_file> import <model>` in `__init__.py` for each one of your models, each model must be imported into `models/__init__.py`

Comment: My __init__.py is now empty. Should it contain imports ?

Comment: Yes, `models/__init__.py` should contain imports, see my comment above

Comment: It works well, thanks. Now I can flush my model. Do you have any piece of documentation that gives instruction to put the imports on __init__.py ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package